# .NET Custom Control (i.e. Button) Build & Run Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, button, resize

I have an issue with a custom .NET control i have created.
If i place the control on a form. I can resize as I please.
As soon as i Build or Run the project the control defaults back to its originally placed size!

Any ideas?

Custom Control:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class KRC4Button
Inherits Button

Private CheckBox As CheckBox
Private FillColorGradiant As Color = Color.FromArgb(151, 151, 151)
Private FillColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(233, 233, 233)
Private PressedFillColorGradiant As Color = Color.FromArgb(108, 200, 255)
Private PressedFillColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(2, 170, 255)
Private DisabledColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200)
Private BorderColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100)
Private DisabledBorderColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170)
Private TextColor As Color = Color.Black
Private DisabledTextColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(136, 136, 136)
Private _CheckBoxVisible As Boolean = False
Private _Checked As Boolean = False
Private BorderPenpenWidth As Single = 1.0F
Private BorderPen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black, BorderPenpenWidth)
Private KRC4Font As Font = New Font("Tahoma", 13.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
Private IsPressed As Boolean = False
Private Radius As Integer = 7

Public Property CheckBoxVisible As Boolean
    Get
        Return _CheckBoxVisible
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _CheckBoxVisible = value
        Refresh()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Checked As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Checked
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _Checked = value
        Refresh()
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
    CheckBox = New CheckBox
    CheckBox.Text = ""
    CheckBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Me.Controls.Add(CheckBox)

    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, True)
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim BackgroundBrush, TextBrush As Brush
    Dim StringSize As New SizeF(e.Graphics.MeasureString(Text, KRC4Font))

    If Enabled Then
        TextBrush = New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Me.Height), Me.TextColor, Me.TextColor)
        If IsPressed Then
            BackgroundBrush = New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Me.Height), Me.PressedFillColor, Me.PressedFillColorGradiant)
        Else
            BackgroundBrush = New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Me.Height), Me.FillColor, Me.FillColorGradiant)
        End If
        BorderPen.Color = Me.BorderColor
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackgroundBrush, ClientRectangle)
    Else
        TextBrush = New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Me.Height), Me.DisabledTextColor, Me.DisabledTextColor)
        BackgroundBrush = New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Me.Height), Me.DisabledColor, Me.DisabledColor)
        BorderPen.Color = Me.DisabledBorderColor
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(BackgroundBrush, ClientRectangle)
    End If

    Me.MinimumSize = New Size(66, 40)
    Me.MaximumSize = New Size(0, 40)

    CheckBox.Visible = CheckBoxVisible
    CheckBox.Checked = Checked
    CheckBox.Location = New Point(5, Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2) - Convert.ToInt32(CheckBox.Height / 2))

    e.Graphics.DrawArc(BorderPen, New Rectangle(0, 1, Radius, Radius), 180, 90)
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(BorderPen, New Rectangle(Width - Radius, 0, Radius, Radius), 270, 90)
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(BorderPen, New Rectangle(Width - Radius, Height - Radius, Radius, Radius), 0, 90)
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(BorderPen, New Rectangle(1, Height - Radius, Radius, Radius), 90, 90)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(BorderPen, 0.0F, 0.0F, CType((Width - 1), Single), CType((Height - 1), Single))

    ' text centred in button
    If CheckBoxVisible Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, KRC4Font, TextBrush, 20, Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2) - Convert.ToInt32(StringSize.Height / 2))
    Else
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, KRC4Font, TextBrush, Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2) - Convert.ToInt32(StringSize.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32(Height / 2) - Convert.ToInt32(StringSize.Height / 2))
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetLeftUpper(ByVal e As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return New Rectangle(0, 0, e, e)
End Function

Private Function GetRightUpper(ByVal e As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return New Rectangle(Width - e, 0, e - 1, e - 1)
End Function

Private Function GetRightLower(ByVal e As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return New Rectangle(Width - e - 1, Height - e, e, e)
End Function

Private Function GetLeftLower(ByVal e As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return New Rectangle(0, Height - e, e, e)
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub OnValidated(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub KRC4Button_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    IsPressed = True
End Sub

Private Sub KRC4Button_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
    IsPressed = False
    Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub KRC4Button_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    IsPressed = False
    Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub KRC4Button_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Dim path As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
    path.StartFigure()
    path.AddArc(GetLeftUpper(Radius), 180, 90)
    path.AddLine(Radius, 0, Width - Radius, 0)
    path.AddArc(GetRightUpper(Radius), 270, 90)
    path.AddLine(Width, Radius, Width, Height - Radius)
    path.AddArc(GetRightLower(Radius), 0, 90)
    path.AddLine(Width - Radius, Height, Radius, Height)
    path.AddArc(GetLeftLower(Radius), 90, 90)
    path.AddLine(0, Height - Radius, 0, Radius)
    path.CloseFigure()
    Region = New Region(path)
End Sub
End Class
```

Designer Code:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _

Partial Class KRC4Button
Inherits Button

'Control overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Control Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  Do not modify it
' using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    Me.Name = "KRC4Button"
    Me.Text = "Text"
    Me.MinimumSize = New Size(66, 40)
    Me.MaximumSize = New Size(0, 40)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Because when you instantiate it (new) it's going to default to the original size... Also you are inheriting a button, but are using a checkbox?

Comment: Thanks, so how do i go about not making it default to the original size? the checkbox is to have a different version of the button. Also please see updated question with the designer code.